# What tribe are the Bene Israel in India descended from?

Tags: chutz-laaretz, genealogy, shevatim-12-tribes

What tribe(s) are the [Bene Israel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bene_Israel) of India descended from?

Comment: heard that they were from Zevulun but needs to be verified

Comment: Where'd you hear that?

Comment: After speaking with a relative I was told this. But he has done much more of a thorough research. http://www.torathmoshe.com/ <- his website. Feel free to ask him.

Comment: However I was also told about a debate whether they were from shevet Yehudah or Reuven