# Rabbinic endorsement of Indians as descendants of Avraham?

Tags: gentiles, communities, abraham

There are some who have suggested that the Indian peoples (or, more specifically, the original Aryan tribes and/or the Brahmin caste) are descendants of Avraham's sons Zimran, Yokshan, Medan, Midian, Yishbak and Shuah, who are described as travelling eastwards from Eretz Yisroel (*Bereshit 25:1-6; Divrei HaYamim A 1:32*). (This is also touched on [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31682/what-happened-to-avrahams-other-sons/35176#35176) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11296/what-happened-to-avrahams-students/11301?s=11%7C0.1037#11301), and tangentially [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55856/are-the-historical-jewish-tribes-still-known-today/55860?s=33%7C0.0485#55860) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26951/what-tribe-are-the-bene-israel-in-india-descended-from?s=1%7C1.3807) on Mi Yodeya.) The "gifts" that Avraham gave to them are interpreted as spiritual knowledge/powers (perhaps alluded to by *Zohar 1:99b*?), which form the origin of the meditation techniques and cosmological investigations in Hindu (and later Buddhist) cultures.

Has this view ever been adopted or endorsed by any rabbinic authorities (whether ancient or current), and if so, in which seforim? (E.g., R. Yona Metzger was the most prominent rabbi involved in the [interfaith Jewish-Hindu Leadership Summit in 2007](http://www.ajc.org/site/apps/nlnet/content3.aspx?c=7oJILSPwFfJSG&b=8451911&ct=12474841). Has he ever come out in support of this position?)

Comment: The only source that comes to mind that indicates what happened to them, besides the zohar, is Hilkhoth Melakhim uMilkhamoth 10:8 which states they became mixed with the Ishmaelites.

Comment: Although this is only my theory based on Sefer HaYashar, it could be that the Hindus come from Zimran's son Abihen.